# Unable to extract data from website via scrapy but works with xpath helper extension

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

So I created a scrapy spider to extract data from a site e.g.
https://www.sportstoto.com.my/result_print.asp?drawNo=5291/21

Here's my code,

```
    import scrapy
from totoprintasp.items import Result


def generate_start_urls():
    drawNums = ['5291/21']
    return ['https://www.sportstoto.com.my/result_print.asp?drawNo={}'.format(drawNum) for drawNum in drawNums]


class TotoprintSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'totoprint'
    allowed_domains = ['www.sportstoto.com.my/result_print.asp']
    start_urls = generate_start_urls()
    download_delay = 3

    def parse(self, response):
        # print(response.body)

        items = []
        # print(response.body)
        for each in response.xpath("/html/body/div/center/table/tbody"):
            item = Result()
            drawDate = each.xpath(
                "tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/span/font/b/text()").extract() 
            drawNo = each.xpath(
                "tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/b/font/text()").extract()
            gameType = each.xpath(
                "tr[4]/td/span/font/text()").extract()
            firstPrize = each.xpath(
                "tr[5]/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/span/b/font/text()").extract()

            item['drawDate'] = drawDate
            item['drawNo'] = drawNo
            item['gameType'] = gameType
            item['firstPrize'] = firstPrize
            items.append(item)
            yield item
```

It didn't extract anything. I am running the command,
`scrapy runspider totoprint.py` and have set, the values,

`FEED_URI = 'results.json'`

`FEED_FORMAT = 'json'`

in my `settings.py` file

So the results should be written to the json file

Funny thing nothing appears and nothing got extract. I've tried different variation, even changed `.extract()` to `.get()`

The XPath works as I've tried it on my XPath helper extension in my chrome browser.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQsu2.png)

Appreciate some help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrite your script but you have to refix it according to your own item. The problem here you're looking for 1 `tbody` with their 1 child. But there a lot of `tbody`.

As I understand you want gameType as a list and others as a string. I get the following output:

```
|------------------|-----------------|----------------------------------------|------------|
| drawDate         | drawNo          | gameType                               | firstPrize |
|------------------|-----------------|----------------------------------------|------------|
| Date:30/05/2021  | DrawNo. 5291/21 | TOTO 4D,TOTO 4D ZODIAC,TOTO 5D,TOTO 6D | 4800       |
|------------------|-----------------|----------------------------------------|------------|
```

By the way, you don't have to do a for loop for each URL. Each URL calling the parse one by one. So here is the script:

```
import scrapy

def generate_start_urls():
    drawNums = ['5291/21']
    return ['https://www.sportstoto.com.my/result_print.asp?drawNo={}'.format(drawNum) for drawNum in drawNums]

class TotoprintSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'totoprint'
    allowed_domains = ['www.sportstoto.com.my/result_print.asp']
    start_urls = generate_start_urls()
    download_delay = 3
    custom_settings = { 
        "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY":False, #You have to close the robotstxt rule because they are not letting you in.
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        drawDate,drawNo = response.xpath('//*[@class="dataDD"]//text()').extract() #Both have same class so you can scrape them together
        gameType = response.xpath('//*[@class="tit4D"]//text()').extract()
        firstPrize = response.xpath('(//*[@class="dataResultA"])[1]//text()').get() #According to your scrit you want just first price because of that I write the xpath with [1]
        yield {
            'drawDate':drawDate.replace("\t","").replace("\n","").replace("\r",""), #There was some issue about t,n,r I delete simply with replace
            "drawNo":drawNo.replace("\t","").replace("\n","").replace("\r",""),
            "gameType":gameType,
            "firstPrize":firstPrize
        }
```

I think the script I write is what you want.

Comment: Hi Murat, Thanks for that. I see what you did there. Using class does make the XPath more efficient. I didn't notice that in DevTools in the beginning. Noticed it again in the breadcrumbs showing 'span.dataDD' <- which suggest drawDate and drawNo both has one of its parent node having a class attribute, dataDD. I will take note of that in the future. As for \t, \r and \n I also did notice it too when I did a print out in the python code. What causes that? Is it common to have this escape code appearing in the html when using scrapy?

Comment: I appreciated that you solve it. It is not too common. Some of the websites preparing their documents like plain text. They are copying the content from a pdf or something because that \t\n or \r appears.